# Jenkins with msbuild

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I am setting CI with .net projects but I having troubles when I try configure the restore using bath command line into Jenkins like this:

C:\nuget.exe restore "path\to\solution.sln"

Jenkins console throws "file not found" for the solution.sln in above command.

- Both nuget.exe and the solution.sln on the path are correct.

Comment: Are you passing absolute Path or Relative Path.... Try with the absolute path first i.e from C:/..../path/to/solution.sln, if that works then switch to relative path.... it gets tricky sometimes  or just try **\path\to\solution.sln ot **\solution.sln

Comment: I am using absolute path. I will try with relative.

Comment: Sometimes Absolute paths are pain .....did you try changing forward slash to back slash or vice versa ... simplest was to test it is to take the path and place it in the browser and you should get the file....let me know if it works :)